# wpf, Style, Setters

Tags: wpf, styles, stackpanel, setter

I've got question about wpf xaml style definitions. When I try to set style in this way:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <StackPanel.Style>
          <Setter Property="BusinessModeler:GraphItemBehaviour.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />
      </StackPanel.Style>
</StackPanel>
```

raises exception with message - `'System.Windows.Setter' is not a valid value for property 'Style'`.

when I use this definition:

```
<Style x:Key="itemBehaviour" > 
    <Setter Property="BusinessModeler:GraphItemBehaviour.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />
</Style>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource itemBehaviour}">
```

everything works fine.

So, what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StackPanel.Style` is a property of type `Style`, so without wrapping the `Setter` in `<Style></Style>` you're trying to set the `Style` property to something of type `Setter`.

```
<StackPanel.Style>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="BusinessModeler:GraphItemBehaviour.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Style>
```